# Layer normalization in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, normalization, normalize

I'm trying to test layer normalization function of PyTorch.

But I don't know why `b[0]` and result have different values here

Did I do something wrong ?

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

a = torch.randn(1, 5)

m = nn.LayerNorm(a.size()[1:], elementwise_affine= False)

b = m(a)
```

Result:

```
input: a[0] = tensor([-1.3549, 0.3857,  0.1110, -0.8456, 0.1486])

output: b[0] = tensor([-1.5561, 1.0386,  0.6291, -0.7967, 0.6851])
```

```
mean = torch.mean(a[0])
var = torch.var(a[0])
result = (a[0]-mean)/(torch.sqrt(var+1e-5))
```

Result:

```
result = tensor([-1.3918, 0.9289, 0.5627, -0.7126, 0.6128])
```

And, for `n*2` normalization , the result of pytorch layer norm is always `[1.0 , -1.0]` (or `[-1.0, 1.0]`) . I can't understand why. Please let me know if you have any hints

```
a = torch.randn(1, 2)

m = nn.LayerNorm(a.size()[1:], elementwise_affine= False)

b = m(a)
```

Result:

```
b = tensor([-1.0000, 1.0000])
```

Answer (score 0):

For calculating the variance use `torch.var(a[0], unbiased=False)`. Then you will get the same result. By default pytorch calculates the unbiased estimation of the variance.

Answer (score 0):

For your **1st question**, as @Theodor said, you need to use `unbiased=False` unbiased when calculating variance.

**Only if you want to explore more:** As your input size is 5, unbiased estimation of variance will be `5/4 = 1.25` times the biased estimation. Because unbiased estimation uses `N-1` instead of `N` in the denominator. As a result, each value of `result` that you generated, is `sqrt(4/5) = 0.8944` times the values of `b[0]`.

About your **2nd question**:

> And, for n*2 normalization , the result of pytorch layer norm is always `[1.0 , -1.0]`

This is reasonable. Suppose only two elements are `a` and `b`. So, mean will be `(a+b)/2` and variance `((a-b)^2)/4`. So, the normalization result will be `[((a-b)/2) / (sqrt(variance)) ((b-a)/2) / (sqrt(variance))]` which is essentially `[1, -1]` or `[-1, 1]` depending on `a > b` or `a < b`.